How to group text to lines if there is small difference in Y position
Using PdfPig to read text from order PDF as described in Get Text Line By Line From PDF using C# answer
  static void GetWordsInReadingOrder(UglyToad.PdfPig.Content.Page page, StringBuilder builder)
  { 
    var words = page.GetWords().ToList();
    var wordsList = page.GetWords().GroupBy(x => x.BoundingBox.Bottom);
    foreach (var word in wordsList)
    {
      bool esimene = true;
      foreach (var item in word)
      {
        if (!esimene)
          builder.Append(' ');
        esimene = false;
        builder.Append($"{item.Text}");
      }
      builder.AppendLine();
    }
  }

Splits single PDF line to multiple lines if there is small difference in x.BoundingBox.Bottom.
How to add some tolerance so that if there is small difference in Y positons, items appear in same line?
Probably rounding should added to
var wordsList = page.GetWords().GroupBy(x => x.BoundingBox.Bottom);

I created this code to consider distance from start of row and to sort before and after assigning. Can this improved?
var sorted = (from r in page.GetWords()
                    orderby r.BoundingBox.Bottom, r.BoundingBox.Left
                    select r).ToList();

if (sorted.Count == 0)
  return;
List<WordsWithLines> lines = new List<WordsWithLines>();
const double rowHeight = 10;
double lnLastTop = 0;
int lnLastRow = 1;
double csvReaVpos = sorted.First().BoundingBox.Bottom;
foreach (var r in sorted)
{
  if (r.BoundingBox.Bottom >= (lnLastTop + 0.5 * rowHeight) || (r.BoundingBox.Bottom  - csvReaVpos) > rowHeight)
  {
    ++lnLastRow;
    csvReaVpos = r.BoundingBox.Bottom;
  }
  lnLastTop = r.BoundingBox.Bottom;
  lines.Add(new WordsWithLines()
  {
    RowNo = lnLastRow,
    WordElement = r
  });
}
var wordsList = from r in lines
                orderby r.RowNo descending, r.WordElement.BoundingBox.Left
                select r;

int rowNo = wordsList.First().RowNo;
bool first = true;
foreach (var word in wordsList)
{
  if (rowNo != word.RowNo)
  {
    builder.AppendLine();
    first = true;
    rowNo = word.RowNo;
  }
  if (!first)  
      builder.Append(' ');
    builder.Append($"{Core.CharTran(word.WordElement.Text, " ", "_")}");
  first = false;
}


Please don't use PDFBox tags when this isn't about PDFBox.

If I understand correclty, you would like to have some way to put objects into "buckets" if some decimal/double value is "close enough". For that I can suggest quite straight forward implementation:
Go over all the decimal values in question, first create first bucket with first item, and for each next item check if matching bucket exist (based on max difference between them), if no such bucket exists, create new one.
Below is implementation with sample extension method:
public static class Bucketing
{
    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<double, T>> BucketGroupBy<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> collection,
        Func<T, double> selector,
        double bucketRange)
    {
        var buckets = GetBuckets(
            collection.Select(selector).ToArray(),
            (x, y) => Math.Abs(x - y) < bucketRange);

        var newSelector = (T x) =>
        {
            var decimalValue = selector(x);
            var bucket = buckets.First(i => i.Value.Contains(decimalValue));
            return bucket.Key;
        };

        return collection.GroupBy(newSelector);
    }

    public static Dictionary<double, double[]> GetBuckets(
        double[] numbers,
        Func<double, double, bool> bucketPredicate)
    {
        var buckets = new Dictionary<double, List<double>>();
        foreach (var number in numbers)
        {
            var existingBucket = buckets.FirstOrDefault(x => bucketPredicate(x.Key, number));

            if(existingBucket.Value is not null)
            {
                existingBucket.Value.Add(number);
                continue;
            }

            buckets.Add(number, new List<double> { number });
        }

        return buckets.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.ToArray());
    }
}


I added my code to solution. Will your Bucketing class create same rows? Also after assigning row numbers words should re-ordered to put thim in correct order. How to improve this code?
